# FORM not posting to PayPal

Tags: html, forms, post, paypal

I'm having a very annoying problem with a form on my website.
The form is a payment form that posts to PayPal.

But I keep getting complaints saying that it is simply **not loading the PayPal payment page after clicking submit**.

Obviously this is a big problem for me because it's causing me too loose potential customers.
If anybody has any thoughts on this issue it would be very much appreciated.

This is the FORM:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST" style="margin-top: 6px;">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="billing@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://mysite.com/premium.php">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mysite.com/premium.php?action=done">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mysite.com/payment.php?action=ipn">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Premium">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="4.95">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="text" id="username" name="custom" value="Please enter your Twitter username here...">
<input type="image" src="/images/prebtn.png" id="signup" value="Signup for Premium" style="margin: 0;">
</form>
```

If you need any more information just ask, Thank you.

Comment: Sorry no one else has been able to help you before now, I can appreciate how frustrated and annoyed you must be! Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a problem in your code either, but I have found the following page that may be of use to you: https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics!

Comment: Can I ask also, has this form ever worked? AND if so, since when has it stopped working? Are the any conditions that make it work?

Comment: Thanks for the comments,  the form has always worked. But I assume has always had problems as well. It was only recently that I started getting more complaints since I introduced a contact system for the error.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. It's very intermittent. Typically, pretty infrequent. But when I get complaints, it's usually iPhone or iPad using Safari. If I tell the person to try a different browser, it works. 

I have plenty of people with iPhone/iPad without a problem. Also, can't determine if it's old versions, I ask, often they say it's brand new, etc. Super annoying.

Comment: I am having the same problem - 8 years later - and it is driving me nuts.  Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should have your input submit inside the form tags.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up for Premium"/>
```

**UPDATE**

I just tried your code in a new HTML file with no changes, and **it works perfectly**, it redirects me to paypal to pay £4.95.

- Create a new HTML file, and paste the code you posted in your question inside the body tag.
- Click the submit img, and it redirects you to paypal.

I dont know why its not working in your project, perhaps invalid html (missing tags somewhere?, javascript overriding the click and doing nothing?).

**But your code does work**, We need more code and information as to the page that this code is on to find out why its not working.

Comment: This cannot be the solution, since `<input type="image" />` can also be used to submit a form. Futhermore, the `submit` button does not contain a name attribute, so it's not doing anything.

Comment: I did look that up, and as Rob says, `<input type="image">` is a perfectly fine solution. Besides, that is not the problem! When I tried the code, it just sends me to a blank page, so obviously the submission of the form is correct!